# Problems that are NP-hard to approximate even when the input graph is regular

Tags: graph-theory, approximation-hardness

Are there graph problems which are NP-hard to approximate even when the input graph is regular?

For instance, are there optimization problems that are NP-hard to approximate within $O(n^\epsilon)$ even when the input graph is regular?

PS: The input graph is a simple undirected graphs

Comment: If you want a combinatorial problem, i'm pretty sure there exist one though I couldn't say which in particular. If you accept cheating answer then you can interpret your planar graph as encoding a Turing machine.

Comment: You can take any graph you want and add self loops to make it regular. Doing so won't change (for instance) Hamiltonicity.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt  Oh, I meant only simple graphs.

Comment: Hamiltonian cycle is hard on 3 regular graphs ( even if you insist on three connected and planar). Counting simple cycled will be hard to approximate on such graphs, because you can replace vertices with gadgets that cause an exponential blow up in the proportion of simple cycles that are longest. The gadget used in the triangulation case here https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.08881 should work.

Comment: (There are certainly simpler examples -- the gadget in that paper was cooked up to control a lot of parameters at once. If you just want to control 3-regularity, maybe iteratively replacing vertices by triangles would work?)

Comment: @LorenzoNajt Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Acyclic Matching Problem is APX-complete also for regular graphs. 
See [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-48966-3_31).

Comment: @AmirNikabadi Please post it as an answer (preferably with a brief description of the problem to keep it self contained)

Answer (score 1):

For all $k\geq 3$, the problem maximum induced matching is APX-hard for $k$-regular bipartite graphs. See [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397513000893) paper.

A matching $M$ of a graph $G$ is induced if for every pair of edges $e,e'$ in M, there is no edge between them in $G$.

Comment: Also, maximum induced matching is APX-complete for cubic planar graphs (see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570866704000371)